# Sending notifications on build failure in Bamboo server

Tags: bamboo

I want to configure the Bamboo notification in a way that

1. When a build fails on the bamboo server a notification mail should go the developer responsible for the build failure. This is achieved and works fine.
2. Also the notification about the build failure should go to the developer's respective supervisor (say his/her scrum master and product owner). How to achieve this?

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 4):

It is possible. In Bamboo 4.x (and i think also in Bamboo 5.x) you can set this kind of notification here: **Configure Plan->Notifications** 
[image: Notification Settings View]
On this site, you have a few options. You can select in the Event dropdown menu for example *"Failed Builds And First Successful"* and in Recipient Type *"Committers"*.

You can add multiple notification rules.